# scp, find files by names on remote and copy to local

Tags: scp

I need copy all files from remote folder (there are subfolders) filtered by name to local, but with the same subfolder structure.

**I did**

```
./sshpass -p 'XXX' scp -r tpx@192.168.1.6:/app/eretail/gaia/web/eti/*new.html .
```

But this copied files only in root folder. On remote is for example `01new.html` file in subfolder `01` and I need to copy this files too, with same subfolder structure. So for example like this.

**Remote**

```
/app/eretail/gaia/web/eti/02new.html
/app/eretail/gaia/web/eti/01/01new.html
/app/eretail/gaia/web/eti/01/test.html
```

**Local (expected result)**

```
./02new.html
./01/01new.html
```

How can I do this? Do I have to use `find`? How?

Thanks.

EDIT: `rsync` is not possible.

Comment: You can use `tar` (on the remote) and "un"`tar` (on local) in a pipe and add the `--include` option in the remote `tar` command. And use `ssh` instead of `scp`, of course...

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned in my comment above about the `--include` option of the `tar` command. However, the GNU `tar` command does not contain an `--include` option. So the correct answer would be this:

```
./sshpass -p 'XXX' \
  ssh tpx@192.168.1.6 "cd /app/eretail/gaia/web/eti/ ; \
    find . -name '*new.html' -print0 | tar -cvf - --null -T -" \
  | tar -xvf -
```

Here, we are using `ssh` instead of `sftp`. `ssh` will run the commands `cd`, `find` and first `tar` on the *remote* server, to "tar" the files found by `find` on to ***`stdout`***. The last `tar` command will run on the *local* machine to "un-tar" the files coming from ***`stdin`*** into the current directory.

Comment: Thanks, but on the remote server is some problem - `find: bad option -print0
find: path-list predicate-list
tar: --null: No such file or directory
tar: -T: No such file or directory
tar: -: No such file or directory`

Comment: I think you are using very old versions of Ubuntu. In this case and assuming your file names do not contain special characters like newlines, you can commit the `-print0` and `--null` parameters.

Comment: I mean, **omit** the `-print0` and `--null` parameters from the command I have shown.

Comment: Oh, this is very old server, even not Ubuntu. :/ Sorry for this, it is old AIX. But I have solution. Should I import my solution as answer, or as updated question? Thanks.

Comment: You can answer your own question, if my answer is not suitable for you. That is perfectly acceptable!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @FedonKadifeli for answer, it led me in the right direction. Seems his solution is worked, but I am afraid not for old AIX grandpa.

I did it this way, maybe for somebody useful.

```
./sshpass -p 'XXX' ssh tpx@192.168.1.6 "
    cd /app/eretail/gaia/web/eti/
    find . -name '*new.html' -exec tar -rvf etikety-html.tar {} \;
"

./sshpass -p 'XXX' scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no tpx@192.168.1.6:/app/eretail/gaia/web/eti/etikety-html.tar .

tar -xvf etikety-html.tar
```